# Is this question on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Link to question: [Why do bullets in a magazine go up instead of down?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56027/why-do-bullets-in-a-magazine-go-up-instead-of-down)

Is this question acceptable or not? The answers seem to suggest it is only based off of ergonomic choices, and I"m not sure if this is the right site for it.

If so, how should I tag it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Personally, I don't think it's on topic here. It's not asking about a physics concept. But multiple people have posted answers and not VTC'd or flagged the question, indicating that they think it's on topic. We'll have to have some community discussion to figure this one out.

Incidentally, the fact that you're not finding good tags for the question is probably a sign that it may not be on topic.

Comment: If it's about the design choice, as to how physics may have played a role into how the weapons were made, would it still be on-topic?

Comment: In my opinion: asking that question means you're fishing for a physics concept to try to make the question on topic. So no, I would not think asking it that way makes a difference. (Actually, that kind of _is_ what you're asking.)

Comment: I didn't VTC because questions of the form "shouldn't xxx physical law have come into play here?" seem inherently on-topic, *even if* the correct answer is "actually no - the laws of physics give us flexibility here, so non-physical considerations dictate what happens." One can explain *why* the laws of physics are non-constraining, for instance.